# Showing that $\mathfrak{Re}(a\overline{b}) = |a||b|$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ with $a\overline{b} \geq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

My CA book states that $|a + b| = |a| + |b|$ if and only if $a\overline{b} \geq 0$. The if-part of the statement is quite easy. However I'm not entirely sure how to conclude (or to convince myself about) the only if. Namely, $|a + b|^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2\mathfrak{Re}(a\overline{b}) = (|a| + |b|)^2 + 2\mathfrak{Re}(a\overline{b}) - 2|a||b|$. By assumption $\mathfrak{Re}(a\overline{b})\geq 0$, so it's certainly possible that $\mathfrak{Re}(a\overline{b}) = |a||b|$. By writing $a = x_1 + iy_1, b = x_2 + iy_2, x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and assuming the claimed equality, after squaring both sides one has $(x_1x_2)^2 + (y_1y_2)^2 + 2x_1x_2y_1y_2 = (x_1^2 + y_1^2)(x_2^2 + y_2^2) \Longleftrightarrow (x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x_1y_2 = x_2y_1$. But I don't see how I could apply here the fact that $x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 \geq 0$ to conclude the proof.

Comment: If $a\overline{b}$ is real and non-negative, then, like every non-negative real number, it is equal to its absolute value (or equivalently, complex modulus). Can you finish from there?

Comment: Hint: write $\bar{b}=c/a$ with $c>0$, then compute $|b|$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks! I somehow missed the fact that for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ the order relation to make sense implies that $\mathfrak{Re}(z) = z$.

Comment: @SickSeries The case $a\bar b=0$ is trivially true, otherwise if $\,a\bar b = c \gt 0\,$ then $\,a = \dfrac{c}{\overline b} = \underbrace{\dfrac{c}{|b|^2}}_{\gt \, 0} \,b\,$.

Comment: I don't want to bump the question needlessly, but if you have the chance to edit, could you please remove the `complex-geometry` tag? (The `geometry` tag is appropriate.)